# How can I break my html table up into chunks django python

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

So for example I have a table with 3 rows and 100 columns. What I would like to do is split it up by tens so the first table has 3 rows then 10 columns and so on until I have 10 tables all with equal 3 rows and 10 columns. The catch is I dont want repeats so in table one it should be 1-10 then table 2 it should be 11-20 and so on and so on...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I would like to do this using a python way and not css.

Here is my view.

```
@login_required
def shipping_pdf(request, id):
  sheet_data = Sheet.objects.get(pk=id)
  work_order = sheet_data.work_order
  purchase_order = sheet_data.purchase_order
  drawing = sheet_data.drawing_number
  draw_rev = sheet_data.drawing_revision
  part = sheet_data.part_number
  part_rev = sheet_data.part_revision
  customer_data = Customer.objects.get(id=sheet_data.customer_id)
  customer_name = customer_data.customer_name 
  title_head = 'Shipping-%s' % sheet_data.work_order
  complete_data = Sheet.objects.raw("""select s.id, d.id d_id, s.work_order, d.target, i.reading, d.description, i.serial_number from app_sheet s left join app_dimension d on s.id = d.sheet_id
  left join app_inspection_vals i on d.id = i.dimension_id where s.id = %s""" % id)

  for c_d in complete_data:
    dim_description = Dimension.objects.filter(sheet_id=c_d.id).values_list('description', flat=True).distinct()

    dim_id = Dimension.objects.filter(sheet_id=c_d.id)[:1]
    for d_i in dim_id:
      dim_data = Inspection_vals.objects.filter(dimension_id=d_i.id)
      reading_data = Inspection_vals.objects.filter(dimension_id=d_i.id)      

  key_list = []
  vals_list = []

  for xr in complete_data:

    key_list.append(xr.description)
    vals_list.append(xr.reading)

    #print reading_desc
    sample_size = dim_data  
  reading_desc = {} 
  for i in range(len(key_list)):
    if key_list[i] in reading_desc:
      reading_desc[key_list[i]].append(vals_list[i])
    else: 
      reading_desc[key_list[i]]=[vals_list[i]]

      print reading_desc
  return render_to_pdf(
     'app/shipping_pdf.html',  
     {
       'work_order': work_order, 
       'sample_size': sample_size,
       'customer_name': customer_name,
       'title': title_head, 
       'reading_desc': reading_desc, 
       'purchase_order': purchase_order,
       'drawing': drawing,
       'draw_rev': draw_rev,
       'part': part,
       'part_rev': part_rev,

    }                     
  )
```

here is my html.

```
      <table style="border: 2px solid black;">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Serial Number</th>
          {% for ss in sample_size %}
             <th>{{ ss.serial_number }}</th>
          {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           {% for key, values in reading_desc.items %}
           <tr> 
             <td>{{key}}</td>
             {% for v in values %}
               <td>{{v}}</td>
             {% endfor %}
          </tr>
           {% endfor %}
        </tbody> 
      </table>
```

Here is what it looks like now *notice its all squished.

[image: Before]

Here is what I would like it to look like.

[image]

Tried a suggestion made still no luck now I have a new error

```
      <table style="border: 2px solid black;">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Serial Number</th>
          {% for ss in sample_size %}
             <th>{{ ss.serial_number }}</th>
          {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           {% for i in range(10) %} 
             {% for j in range(100) %} 
               {% for key, values in reading_desc.items.i*j %}
               <tr> 
                 <td>{{key}}</td>
                 {% for v in values %}
                   <td>{{v}}</td>
                 {% endfor %}
               </tr>
               {% endfor %}
             {% endfor %}
           {% endfor %}
        </tbody> 
      </table>
```

Could not parse the remainder: '(100)' from 'range(100)'

Comment: I am not going to code it for you, but the simple logic is that instead of running a foreach loop, run a nested loop, with the inner loop counting 1 to 10 and the outer loop counting from 1 to (total columns)/10. Simple logic to be performed in the template.

Comment: That's the part I can't figure out how to go about doing that with the data I am dealing with @SwakeertJain

Comment: for i in range(100):
    for j in range(10):
        {{ reading_desc.i*j }}

Something like this should do it..

Comment: I updated my question with your comment suggestion. @Swakeert Jain

Comment: dude common, you just copy pasted that. It was to help with the algo, it wasn't template code. Lol, do some coding brother. :/

Comment: I am a newbie to python in general I come from a ruby background. I wouldn't of asked the question if I knew how to do it. @SwakeertJain